# uWSGI config error 'core/socket.c' - w/ Django & NGINX

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi, digital-ocean

I'm setting up a Django site on Ubuntu 14.04 (Digital Ocean Droplet) using NGINX & uWSGI (following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) w/ out making a second project). I can run my Django site with manage.py. I can also run `uwsgi --http :8080 --home /home/andrew/Env/personalsitevenv --chdir /home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite -w personalsite.wsgi` without any issues. I can see my site running at my IP:Port. I can also run `uwsgi --http :8000 --module personalsite.wsgi --virtualenv /home/andrew/Env/personalsitevenv` without issue.

When I go to my server's IP all I see is the `Welcome to nginx!` page. There aren't any NGINX log errors & `sudo service nginx configtest` is clean. The only information I'm getting is in my log file that I set up for uWSGI which contains:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.12 (64bit) on [Fri Jul  8 00:41:22 2016] ***
compiled with version: 4.8.4 on 05 July 2016 17:45:39
os: Linux-4.4.0-28-generic #47~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 16:30:35 UTC 2016
nodename: **********
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/sites
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
chdir() to /home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite
your processes number limit is 1832
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): No such file or directory [core/socket.c line 230]
```

Can anyone spot any configuration issues or anything else that might be wrong here?

---

/etc/uwsgi/sites/personalsite.ini

```
[uwsgi]
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/log.txt

project = personalsite
base = /home/andrew
repo = andrew-django-personal-site

chdir = %(base)/%(repo)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/personalsitevenv
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = $(base)/%(repo)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
chown-socket = www-data
vacuum = true
```

/etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid andrew
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/personalsite

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite/personalsite.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your **include         uwsgi_params;** has to be the absolute path like **/home/andrew/conf/uwsgi_params** or any other recognizable location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the personalsite.ini file contains socket path as a pattern which might have 0 or more matches, that might not match the real path, so updating it to the absolute path will resolve the problem.

in your personalsite.ini:
if you replace

```
socket = $(base)/%(repo)/%(project)/%(project).sock
```

with the absolute path of your socket's location

```
socket = /home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite/personalsite.sock
```

this will solve the problem.

Once you know the socket location you can design a pattern that will match it.

Sample location in nginx config:

```
location / {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/andrew/andrew-django-personal-site/personalsite/personalsite.sock;
    include /your_location/conf/uwsgi_params; // or your own
    uwsgi_modifier1 30;          // ignore extra if not used
    proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization; // only use if needed
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr; // only use if needed
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;// only if needed
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host; // only use if needed
    proxy_redirect  off;  // only use if needed
}
```

Comment: Hi going off of your comment on `include uwsgi_params`, the tutorial I used, this other [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04), and all others I have seen say that `include uwsgi_params` is fine for simple setups. I've set up another site just using this. I don't have a special uwsgi params configuration so it uses the default at `/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params`.

Comment: All of these other config variables seem like extra for more advanced setup. Can you pinpoint one of them that would be causing my error in the uwsgi log file?

Comment: It looks like the socket location you've specified in your personalsite.ini does not exist, so it has to be specified explicitly like socket = /var/run/uwsgi/mysocket.sock  or verified to be there according to the format.

Comment: I changed `/etc/uwsgi/sites/personalsite.ini` line `socket = /var/run/uwsgi/personalsite.sock` & `/etc/nginx/sites-available/personalsite` line `uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/personalsite.sock;` which got rid of the error. I don't understand why my previous socket definition wasn't correct - can you explain why?

Comment: If you update your answer with this solution from the comments then I'll accept it, thank you for the help.

Comment: FYI for anyone reading this in the future - I also had to add the line `server_name <IP Address Here>;` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/personalsite` to be able to access my site by IP address in a web browser.

Comment: Your previous declaration was a format expression, which may potentially fit zero ore more results, so the real location of your socket file did not adhere the pattern specified, and as such, either the pattern had to change to work for the location, or the location had to be explicitly specified. Now, once you have your location known, you can construct the pattern on a way that will match the location, and once you test it, you can set it back to an expression.

Comment: Shortly speaking, the pattern you used was not identifying the real location.

Comment: If you update your answer to explain changing the socket paths then I'll accept it (so future users can benefit easily by reading the answer and not the comments).